# Angular 6 - How to use an Observable in a service to wait until Okta token exists in localstorage

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my application, I am using third party authentication to log a user in and then set a token in his localstorage.  I'm writing a service to cache the profile information, which takes that user's auth token and calls a `getUser()` backend method to give me back the user profile information.

The issue is that there is a slight delay between the time when the token is set in localstorage and when the app is relying on the token to make the backend call upon initialization.

```
export class UserService {
  private userProfileSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Enduser>(new Enduser());
  userProfile$ = this.userProfileSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private _adService: AdService,
    private _authService: AuthnService) { }

  setUserProfile() {
    const username = this._authService.getUser();
    this.userProfile$ = this._adService.getUser(username).pipe( 
      first(),
      map(result => result[0]),
      publishReplay(1),
      refCount()
    );
    return this.userProfile$;
  }
}
```

This is the synchronous method which checks the localstorage token and returns the username.

```
public getUser(): string {
    const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService()

    const token = localStorage.getItem(environment.JWT_TOKEN_NAME);
    if (!token || jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      const t = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
      return t.username;
    }
  }
```

So `this._authService.getUser();` needs to complete before I can use it in `this._adService.getUser(username)`.

I figured the way to do this would be to make the `getUser()` method return an Observable and `takeWhile` until the value is `!== null`.  Or with `timer`.  Been trying this for a couple hours without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

__

Edit:

This seems to work, but using `timer` strikes me as pretty hacky, and I'd rather do it another way:

In `user.service.ts`:

```
  setUserProfile() {
    timer(100).pipe(
      concatMap(() => {
        const username = this._authService.getUser();
        return this._adService.getUser(username)
      }),
      map(res => res[0])
    ).subscribe(profile => {
      this.userProfileSubject.next(profile);
    });
  }
```

In `app.component.ts` `ngOnInit`

```
this._userService.setUserProfile();
    this._userService.userProfile$.pipe(
      map((user: Enduser) => this._userService.setUserPermissions(user)),
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    ).subscribe();
```

Edit 2: Working Solution

`isLoggedIn()` is the method in which local storage is set.  Here, I'm waiting for it to be set before continuing on to fetch the user profile information.

```
this._authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
      concatMap(() => {
        const username = this._authService.getUser();
        return this._adService.getUser(username)
      }),
      map(res => res[0])
    ).subscribe(profile => {
      this.userProfileSubject.next(profile);
    });
  }
```

isLoggedIn:

```
isLoggedIn(state): Observable<boolean> {

    ...

    return this.http.get(url, {withCredentials: true}).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        const token = res.mdoc.token;

        if (token) {
          localStorage.setItem(environment.JWT_TOKEN_NAME, token);
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense... if `this._authService.getUser()` is synchronous, then what do you mean it "needs to complete before I can use it"? It will always complete before the next line is executed because it's synchronous.

Comment: Dude, honestly, you are making your code more complex and unreadable than it needs to be. How do you know Okta will be done after 100ms every time? In the real world you'll run into latency and such things...this is not a good solution. Keep it simple...just don't invoke `setUserProfile` until your Okta has completed, instead of doing all this needless hacky timer logic. Read my recent comment on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, your problem of wanting to wait for `this._authService.getUser()` to complete doesn't make sense, because if `this._authService.getUser()` is synchronous (as stated by you), then it will always complete before the next line of code is executed.

Anyways, after reading your code I think I know what you are trying to do...

1. Get a username form `this._authService.getUser()`
2. Pass the username to `this._adService.getUser()`
3. Wait for `this._adService.getUser()` to complete and pass it's value to your observable stream, `userProfile$`

To achieve that, you don't need any of those fancy RxJS operators; your code can be as simple as:

```
export class UserService {
  private userProfileSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Enduser>(new Enduser());
  userProfile$ = this.userProfileSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private _adService: AdService,
    private _authService: AuthnService
  ) {}

  setUserProfile() {
    const username = this._authService.getUser();

    this._adService.getUser(username).subscribe((userProfile: Enduser) => {
      this.userProfileSubject.next(userProfile);
    });
  }
}
```

Just emit to the `userProfile$` stream as I am doing above, and subscribe to that where ever you want in your app to get the user profile data.

Now anywhere in your app, you can do this to get the user profile data whenever it's sent down the stream:

```
constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
  _userService.userProfile$.subscribe((userProfile: Enduser) => {
    console.log(userProfile);
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right: it must not be synchronous or I wouldn't have this problem.  The issue with the above is that `this._authService.getUser();` comes back as `null` the first time (which has been the problem with all my attempts).  What do you think?

Comment: Go to Developer Tools and manually look inside your local storage. Ask yourself a few questions: 1. Does the token actually exist in local storage? 2. If so, is it expired? If it's not expired, your code logic might be bad. If it is expired, there's your problem. Your code returns null when it's expired. But this shouldn't be an issue of it being synchronous or asynchronous as the localStorage API is all synchronous.

Comment: If I put a `console.log(token)` after `const token = localStorage.getItem(environment.JWT_TOKEN_NAME);` in `getUser()`, the initial value of `token` is null.

We are using Okta for authentication, and the token is being set, but slightly after the app is being loaded.  I put a `timeout(100)` in `setUserProfile()`—by that time the token has shown up.  I've updated with the latest above.

Comment: Ok, so the issue isn't local storage, but the fact that data isn't stored there until after a few milliseconds. I would try to figure out how to defer the execution of the `setUserProfile` logic until _after_ Okta has set the token, however the logic I showed in my example should work just fine. Again, just make sure `setUserProfile` isn't called until Okta sets the token. Do they have some kind of API you can hook into, such as en event that is triggered after the token is set? That is an ideal place to invoke the `setUserProfile` logic.

Comment: Turns out we have a method which actually sets the localstorage token coming from Octa.  So I replaced the `timer` with that.  Appreciate your guidance in taking me that direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
const usernameObs = of(this._authService.getUser());
return usernameObs.pipe(
   flatMap(username => {
    return this._adService.getUser(username).pipe( 
       first(),
       map(result => result[0]),
       publishReplay(1),
       refCount()
    );
}))
```

There is probably a way to remove the nested pipe.  I can't test it but this should work as well, and is a little cleaner:

```
const usernameObs = of(this._authService.getUser());
return usernameObs.pipe(
  flatMap(username => {
    return this._adService.getUser(username);
  }),
  first(),
  map(result => result[0]),
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount()
)
```

Comment: This looks similar to some of my attempts.  The issue, as I state above, is that `this._authService.getUser` returns null the first time.  Can I keep polling it somehow?  Tried using `takeWhile`, but hasn't been working.

Comment: I believe there is a retry() operator. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retry.html

Comment: Never mind that won’t work for you because that only retries in error

Answer (score 0):

My implementation:

```
setUserProfile() {
    this.userProfile$ = this._authService.isLoggedIn(this.activatedRoute.snapshot).pipe(
      concatMap(() => {
        return this._adService.getUser(this._authService.getUser()).pipe(
          map(result => result[0]),
          publishReplay(1),
          refCount()
        );
      })
    )
    return this.userProfile$;
  }
}

_____

// _adService.getUser()

  getUser(username: string): Observable<Enduser> {
    const usernameUrl = encodeURIComponent(username);
    return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}person/${usernameUrl}`).pipe(
      map((res: any) => res.data)
    );
  }

_____

// _authService.getUser()

  public getUser(): string {
    const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService()

    const token = localStorage.getItem(environment.JWT_TOKEN_NAME);
    if (!token || jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      const t = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
      return t.username;
    }
  }
```